# `amplify push` failing - Attribute: StreamArn was not found for resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm having errors when executing the `amplify push` or `amplify push function` commands with the Amplify CLI.

Here's the error in the console (censored project-specific identifiers
):

```
...
UPDATE_FAILED      storage[dynamo db table name]       AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Tue Jan 19 2021 08:32:29 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time) Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:XXX:stack/amplify-XXX-XXX/XXX was not successfully updated. Currently in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS with reason: Attribute: StreamArn was not found for resource: [dynamo db table name]
...
```

I've already tried:

1. Execute `amplify init` again
2. Execute `amplify configure`, create a new IAM user, and use the newly created user's credential.
3. Going back to the commit where `amplify push` last worked, seeing the same error still.
4. Recloned the repo and do the above steps. No luck.

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the AWS Console go to the DynamoDB Table under `Table Overview`, then `Stream Details`, then `Manage Stream`, click `enable both New and Old Images`.

Comment: Glad to help @jdoroy!

Comment: If not too much to ask, can you explain what might have happened that caused the errors?

Comment: Thanks. Fixed for me. In my case this happened because I'd restored a table from an old backup. I'm guessing when amplify generates the tables the Stream settings are setup this way. But a manual creation needs you to take care of it yourself.

Comment: Even if the `enable both New and Old Images` radio button is checked, don't forget to click on the `activate` button below ^^'

Comment: I just want to say how thankful I am for this response @yudhiesh. Amplify in general created very obsure and hard to debug errors due to the nature of it orchestrating so many services. This saved me hours of time. Thank you..thank you....thank you

Comment: An additional step I tripped over is that this needs to be done before the 'amplify import storage' command is used - kinda obvious but took me a while to figure out!

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error when deploy serverless config file, you must add stream type to your dynamodb table like this;

```
TableName:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: id
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: userId
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: id
        KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: userId
        KeyType: RANGE
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 10
      WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    TableName: ${self:custom.TableName}
    StreamSpecification:
      StreamViewType: NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES
```

[StreamSpecification Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-streamspecification.html)